# Is it possible to specify the order of spliting in decision tree with scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

Given three columns, ["A", "B", "C"], can we specify the order of splitting, so that it firstly split on categories of "A", then "B", and then by others?

Based on on documentation page on DecisionTreeClassifier, there is no such option. Is there any way to work it out?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Comment: It's not possible to do this. Tree will automatically choose the feature that give the most reduction in gini/entropy criterion at each node.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to do this. Tree will automatically choose the feature by analyzing the variance across each feature and choosing the split that provides the most benefit.

Further, your model would not perform as efficiently if you chose the split yourself.

Comment: Regarding the "efficientcy", it depends on the data. If these is some dependecy among the features, then specifying particular sequence might help.

Comment: @Girishkumar, No, it does not depend on the data.  Do you understand that the entire point of the algorithm is to find the split that maximizes the efficacy of the splitting?  In machine learning, the application of deterministic rules based on heuristics leads to worse outcomes than rules based on statistics.  This is why the ML pioneers call it statistical learning.